# Why does the colors stop changing after the totalTimer hit +/- 300?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically with this code I'm attempting to make the object's color and emission color to change programatically after a pre-determined time, but whenever the `totalTimer` hits the value of 300 +/-
the colors basically stop changing. I'm using the Unity's version 2019.2.5f1 for this project of mine. Does anyone knows what's wrong?

Also something I've noticed is that whenever I change the value of `frameTimer` to bigger values the value of `totalTimer` to stop changes, but since i'm using `frameTimer` as a frame counter, it wouldn't be beneficial to have a value over 60.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ColorChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region State Variables
    //state variables
    private int frameTimer;
    private int totalTimer = 0;
    private int newSpeed;
    private int colorChanger;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public int NewSpeed
    {
        get => newSpeed;
    }
    #endregion

    Renderer rend;

    public Color[] colors;
    private Color newColor, oldColor;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        newSpeed = 40;
        #region Color instantion
        colors = new Color[9];
        colors[0] = (new Color(0.5098f, 0.3254f, 0.1882f));    //brown
        colors[1] = (new Color(0.8941f, 0.9137f, 0.0392f));    //yellow 
        colors[2] = (new Color(0.1607f, 0.8705f, 0.9568f));    //light blue
        colors[3] = (new Color(1f, 0.5215f, 0.0745f));         //orange
        colors[4] = (new Color(0.7607f, 0.2274f, 0.8588f));    //lightish purple
        colors[5] = (new Color(0.3254f, 0.8588f, 0.2274f));    //green
        colors[6] = (new Color(0.9568f, 0.2470f, 0.1607f));    //red
        colors[7] = (new Color(0.7294f, 0.1490f, 0.1450f));    //crimson
        colors[8] = (new Color(0.0705f, 0.3960f, 0.9019f));    //blue
        #endregion
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        frameTimer++;
        colorChanger++;

        if (frameTimer == 30)
        {
            SpeedChanger(totalTimer++); frameTimer = 0;
           Debug.Log($"The Total Timer is {totalTimer}");
        }

        #region Color Update
        if(colorChanger == newSpeed)
        {
            newColor = colors[Random.Range(0, colors.Length - 1)];

            if(newColor == oldColor)
            {
                while(newColor == oldColor)
                    newColor = colors[Random.Range(0, colors.Length - 1)];
            }
            oldColor = newColor;
            rend.material.SetColor("_Color", newColor);
            rend.material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", newColor);
            rend.material.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
            colorChanger = 0;
            //Debug.Log( $"\n {newColor} this is the frame color");
        }
        #endregion
    }

    private int SpeedChanger(int totalTimer)
    {
        switch(totalTimer)
        {
            case 85:
                newSpeed = 30;
                break;
            case 165:
                newSpeed = 25;
                break;
            case 200:
                newSpeed = 20;
                break;
            case 300:
                newSpeed = 15;
                break;
        }
        return newSpeed; 
    }
}
```

Comment: in your case you dont have anything over 300, why would you expect it to continue changing color?

Comment: @Matriac the `newSpeed` variable affects *how often* the color changes, not the color itself.

Comment: @Jonnyriam, *`whenever I change the value of frameTimer to bigger values the value of totalTimer to stop changes`* Yes, because your conditional is `(frameTimer == 30)`, if you change that value to any value over 30, it will never reset. This is why `>=` is used.

Comment: When `totalTimer`hits 300, newSpeed will be 15. 15 frames later, `SpeedChanger` is called and you won't be able to change `newSpeed` value at all. TotalTimer will continue to grow up and the `newSpeed`value will never change.

Comment: I don't get it. Shouldn't `colorChanger` be reset to 0 every now and then?

Comment: There are just too many errors in this code. There is no semblance of any good practice or design pattern. It will take way to much to entangle that mess. I think you should scrap it and start from scratch.

Comment: Well actually I’m using the rules that were agreed in the convention when C# was formed. Not that I have that much experience in C# but my code is organized at least for me. It’s objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i Figured out what the error is.
The probleme is that if `colorChanger` variable is at lets say 16 and at the same time total timer reach 300, then it would change `newSpeed` to 15 but since `colorChanger` is at 16, it will never change color.
Just change

`if(colorChanger == newSpeed)`

by

`if(colorChanger >= newSpeed)`

Comment: Well but how does that happen? I mean `colorChanger` resets to 0 whenever the loop ends, so it might be a “timing” problem? I didn’t want to put >= due to the fact I want it to be perfectly timed but I guess a microsecond won’t do much

Comment: you reset it to 0 when the color change, but if the newSpeed is modified before the color change and the colorChanger is higher than the new value of newSpeed than it will never reset to 0 because it wont change color